# Get users for given conference openfire

Tags: openfire

How can I get all users that take part in a given conference?

I need users jid's, I have conference jid. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have created next stored procedure:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE GetConferenceUsers

        @conferenceJid nvarchar(MAX) 
    AS

    BEGIN
       SELECT username FROM ofRoster
       WHERE jid = @conferenceJid
    END
```